# Writing to Excel file containing formulas is extremely slow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

We have an automatic process that opens a template excel file, writes rows of data, and returns the file to the user. This process is usually fast, however I was recently asked to add a summary page with some Excel formulas to one of the templates, and now the process takes forever.

It successfully runs with about 5 records after a few minutes, however this week's record set is almost 400 rows and the longest I've let it run is about half an hour before cancelling it. Without the formulas, it only takes a few seconds to run.

Is there any known issues with writing rows to an Excel file that contains formulas? Or is there a way to tell Excel not to evaluate formulas until the file is opened by a user?

The formulas on the summary Sheet are these:

```
' Returns count of cells in column where data = Y
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!J15:Sheet1!J10000, "Y") 
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!F15:Sheet1!F10000, "Y")

' Return sum of column where data is a number greater than 0
' Column contains formula calculating the difference in months between two dates
=SUMIF(Sheet1!I15:Sheet1!I10000,">0",Sheet1!I15:Sheet1!I10000)  

' Returns a count of distinct values in a column
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!D15:Sheet1!D10000<>"")/COUNTIF(Sheet1!D15:Sheet1!D10000,Sheet1!D15:Sheet1!D10000&""))
```

And the code that writes to excel looks something like this:

```
Dim xls as New Excel.Application()
Dim xlsBooks as Excel.Workbooks, xlsBook as Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsSheets as Excel.Sheets, xlsSheet as Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsCells as Excel.Range

xls.Visible = False
xls.DisplayAlerts = False

xlsBooks = xls.Workbooks

xlsBooks.Open(templateFile)
xlsBook = xlsBooks.Item(1)  

' Loop through excel Sheets. Some templates have multiple sheets.
For Each drSheet as DataRow in dtSheets.Rows
    xlsSheets = xlsBook.Worksheets
    xlsSheet = CType(xlsSheets.Item(drSheet("SheetName")), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlsCells = xlsSheet.Cells

    ' Loop though Column list from Database. Each Template requires different columns
    For Each drDataCols as DataRow in dtDataCols.Rows

        ' Loop though Rows to get data
        For Each drData as DataRow in dtData.Rows
            xlsCells(drSheet("StartRow") + dtData.Rows.IndexOf(drData), drDataCols("DataColumn")) = drData("Col" + drDataCols("DataColumn").toString).toString
        Next
    Next
Next

xlsSheet.SaveAs(newFile)
xlsBook.Close
xls.Quit()
```

Comment: Try to set  **manual** calculation mode. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx

Comment: @AVD That worked, thank you :) If you post that as an Answer I'll accept it

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `auto` mode calculation, recalculation occurs after every data input/changed. I had the same problem, was solved by setting `Manual` calculation mode. (Reference MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx).)

```
xls.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
```

Also, this property can only be set after a Workbook has been opened or it will throw a run-time error.

Comment: Thanks. I updated your answer to include a code sample and a note about setting it only after a workbook has been opened.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you write to a cell Excel recalculates the open workbooks and refreshes the screen. Both of these things are slow, so you need to set Application.Screenupdating=false and Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual

Also there is a high overhead associated with each write to a cell, so it is much faster to acuumulate the data in an array and then write the array to the range with a single call to the Excel object model.

Comment: I tried setting `Application.Calculation`, however I get a run-time error (Think it was `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`). I also tried setting `Application.ScreenUpdating`, and that doesn't make a difference. I cannot write to a contigious range of cells because sometimes the templates have their own columns mixed in with the data columns which summarizes data, and I cannot modify the template.

Comment: +1 for "much faster to accumulate the data in an array and then write the array to the range"

Comment: +1 as well. This is a good answer, but AVD answered first with the solution that fixed my problem, so I accepted his answer

Comment: You should be able to either write a column at a time in between the template columns, or read a block of columns that are mixed template stuff and your stuff, modify the array as required, then rewrite the block back. The overhead of accessing a single cell is so large that it will still be faster to read and then write..

Answer (score 0):

One way that has saved me over the years is to add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

directly before I execute a potentially lengthy method, and then

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

directly after, or at least at some later point in the code. This forces Excel to not redraw anything on the visible screen until it is complete That issue is where I've found lengthy running operations to stem from quite often.

Comment: Excel doesn't draw anything on the screen anyways. The file is built on the web server, then saved and returned to the user to download.