# C# ClosedXML : modifying formulas is slow

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I use ClosedXML to build Excel file. For this, I have an Excel file that serves as a template. There is a template row with some formulas.

I use `row.InsertRowsBelow(1)` to add an new row but the method copy formats but not the formulas, so I have to copy them manually with `row.Cell(...).FormulaA1 = ...` but this is extremely slow.

I also try to copy the template row with `row.CopyTo()`, this copy the formulas but slow in the same way.

I have seen the thread (automation) :
[Writing to Excel file containing formulas is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645604/3216022)

So I try to set `excel.CalculateMode = XLCalculateMode.Manual` before manipulate but that changes absolutely nothing.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: Manual calculation will not make any difference for ClosedXML, it makes difference in the other question you linked because they're using Interop, so Excel will calculate every modification. In ClosedXML and other libraries, you're just manipulating the file, there is no formula evaluation and calculation taking place (except if you call `cell.Value`, then [it will try to evaluate](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Evaluating-Formulas))

Comment: Yet if I comment the lines where I set FormulaA1 the result is immediate

Comment: And I don't call cell.Value, the formulas are for example "=D5+F5"